# Probability of combinations of independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Disclaimer: I'm almost 70 and trying to learn math concepts I didn't learn earlier in life. So don't expect this to be a deep or particularly difficult question.

I've always understood the statement that the probabilities of independent events are not affected by the outcomes of their combination. In other words, after 3 heads in a row of a coin toss the 4th toss still only has 0.5 probability of happening. And yet that has always seemed counter intuitive.

If I have 3 tosses the probability of 3 heads is $\frac{1}{8}$. However, if the first head is tossed the odds of tossing two more is $\frac{1}{4}$. Yet the odds on the next toss of a head is still $\frac{1}{2}$. If I had tossed a tail on the first toss, the odds of 3 heads now becomes zero. So, the result of one independent event in a combination does impact the probability of the combination.

Key here, I think are the words "probability of the combination" and not "probability of the next event". If this is correct, this is a significant understanding for me.

Are my assumptions and conclusions correct?

Comment: I think the flaw is in the statement "If I had tossed a tail on the first toss, the odds of 3 heads now becomes zero." If you toss a tail on the first toss, the odds of 3 heads is still $1/8$ if you repeat the whole experiment. Of course in a sense there is "zero chance" to get three heads including the first one if you have already tossed one tail, but that's not the same a priori odds concept any more. The classical concept of probability that you are using here is applicable to events that are yet to be performed and not those that have been partially performed already.

Comment: "The result of one independent event in a combination does impact the probability of the combination": Before the event has happened, it **doesn't**. After the event has happened, the term "probability" is no longer relevant, because the outcome of the event is **already known**.

Comment: If you say that probability is only "applicable to events that are yet to be performed and not those that have been partially performed already" then why are odds calculated on a trifecta after the first race has been run? Clearly if your horse loses the first race you can't win. But if he does win you now have different odds of winning the trifecta than were initially given when you made the bet.